# Using a Relay to command solenoids

Tags: relay

[image][Power to solenoids through relay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbhDg.jpg)[image: GPIO connections to relay]
[image: Spec Sheet]

Hi, I'm newbie and I'm trying to drive solenoids through Pi. I'm not sure about the connection between Pi and Relay and also from Power source to relay and solenoids. Could you help me about these two doubts?
Thank you

Comment: Rather than posting pretty pictures (with illegible markings) you would be better to post specifications of the relay module and which PI PINS YOU ARE USING. Most can be controlled by the Pi, although there are a few (allegedly designed for Arduino) which aren't.

Comment: Sorry, here are the tech spec of the relay:   Elegoo 4 Channel DC 5V Relay Module with Optocoupler for Arduino UNO R3 MEGA 2560 1280 DSP ARM PIC AVR STM32 Raspberry Pi  This relay module is 5V active low. Relay output maximum contact is AC250V 10A and DC30V 10A.
Standard interface can be directly connected with microcontrollers.
Working status indicator lights are conducive to the safe use
4-channel relay interface board, which can be controlled directly by a wide range of microcontrollers such as Arduino, AVR, PIC, ARM, PLC, etc. It is also able to control appliances and other equipments

Comment: As far as the Pi pins are concerned, I plan to use GND, 5V GPIO17, GPIO27 and GPIO22

Comment: 1. **DO NOT** post detail in Comments, edit into your answer. 2. "5V active low" indicates this is probably one of the unsuitable (IMO poorly designed) modules which can only controlled by the Pi with additional circuitry. See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/83495/8697 for comments on similar. There are hundreds of modules controlled by 3.3V logic which are suitable.

Comment: that diagram looks ok, as long as the power supply output voltage matches the rating of the valve solenoids

Comment: The power supply has a 12V output as the solenoids. The 4 relays module may be used with raspberry as the supplier says. I've tried to connect the Pi with the Relay. I've made a little python program and the 4 leds lit correctly andt I've heard the 4 ticks of the relays. Now I try to add the spec sheet to my original post.

Answer (score 1):

Your diagram scares me. Specifically, the 220V label. That potentially fatal voltage combined with inexperience ("newbie") is very risky. If a screw comes loose and line voltage comes into contact with something else, lots of dangerous things can happen. I work with electronics and still choose to purchase a commercial [power relay](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2935?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIzpG_8v_p2wIVApRpCh2v0wYOEAQYASABEgKrpvD_BwE) that I can control with my Raspberry Pi. I'm sure you could find safer alternatives.

If you really do wish to continue with this risky design against all caution, you will also need to use the right relay. Please consult the 05VDC label on your blue relays. Those relays do not really work well with the Raspberry Pi, which has 3.3V GPIO, not 5V. Use a Raspberry Pi relay. Those are Arduino relays.